# Matching anything except two specific strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a RegEx expression for JavaScript that matches anything except two specific strings.

The two things I do not want to match are "{{" and "{:", exactly those.

I wrote:

```
/^(?!{{|{:).*$/
```

However, plugging this expression into regex101 yields *no* matches at all. Where am I going wrong? I've spent hours pouring over online resources just to get this expression, and I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working.

For reference, the target string is:

`{: say|x|Hi{{{x}}}} :}`

Comment: Different approach is to remove those string. FInd [`{[{:]`](https://regex101.com/r/F0uNPW/1) and replace by `''`-empty string. OR to get the result as array of strings `str.split(/{[{:]/)`.

Comment: So do you want to match everything between the two opening and closing brackets? because if so you shouldn't have used the negative look ahead option,..

Comment: @MimArmand I want to match anything that isn't those two strings. So as long as the string isn't "{{" or "{:", I should match it.

Comment: your question shows "{" and "{:" not "{{"

Comment: @JayLane, that's strange. It was edited by another user seconds after posting, so they have amended that. My apologies

Comment: @KommanderKitten no problem just pointing it out, I actually went to correct your post myself but someone had already edited it.

Comment: your regex seems to work fine when tested http://regexr.com/3efmo

Comment: working on regex101 as well https://regex101.com/r/9tCjdR/1

Comment: Regex101 returns no matches with the explanation: "Your regular expression does not match the subject string." This is testing my original expression with the sample text in the OP

Comment: What are the expected resulting matches, or single match, from input string `{: say|x|Hi{{{x}}}} :}`?

Answer (score 0):

To match everything between the two brackets:`\{(.*?)\}$`

To match everything between {: and :} `\{:(.*?)\:}`

Modified version of your code ( worked in one engine and didn't in another!): `((?!{{|{:).)+`

Comment: While these are correct, they don't do quite what I'm looking for. I want to match anything, between anything, at any point in the string, EXCEPT for "{{" and "{:"

Comment: Even if possible at all, Regex is not designed for negative matching, it may be easier to do it in Javascript.

Comment: Your code however may work to some degree and in some regex engines with some modifications:

`((?!{{|{:).)+`

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly, you can use `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/{:|{{2}/g`

```js
var str = "{: say|x|Hi{{{x}}}} :}";
var res = str.replace(/{:|{{2}/g,"");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^.*({{|{:).*$
```

with a negaive conditional (`if`) statement in JavaScript.